# Problem using GDI+ with multiple threads (VB.NET)

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, gdi+

I think it would be best if I just copy and pasted the code (it's very trivial).

```
Private Sub Main() Handles MyBase.Shown
    timer.Interval = 10
    timer.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub tick() Handles timer.Elapsed
    Using g = Graphics.FromImage(image)
        g.Clear(Color.Transparent)
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 0 + i, 0 + i, Me.Width - i, Me.Height - i)
    End Using

    Me.Invalidate()
End Sub
```

An exception, "The object is currently in use elsewhere", is raised during the tick event. Could someone tell me why this happens and how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: What kind of timer is `timer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Handles timer.Elapsed` indicates a System.Timers.Timer.

Use a System.Windows.Forms.Timer instead and your problem cannot happen anymore.

Comment: Good answer. Just pointing out the forms timer synchronizes with it's owner control thread, whereas the system timer you had to manually synchronize before calling cross-thread objects.